# How to cancel a Slide Over secondary app and choose a different app?

Tags: ios, multitasking

I did an iOS 9 app using Xcode 7.0 beta 3.  As shown at [Doing a SlideOver](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html), I did a Slide Over and chose the Calendar app.  In the simulator the device was set to iPad Air 2.  Everything worked fine.  But, when I do a different iOS 9 app and a Slide Over, the Calendar app appears!  How can things be reset so that I can choose any secondary app when doing a Slide Over?  I tried some obvious things like quitting and restarting Xcode, and restarting my Mac Book Pro.

Comment: Thanks atreat! I should have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Pull down from the top of the slideover window.